# jQuery Steps next button not moving to next tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tabbed form set up using jQuery steps, this is working however the next bottom to move to the next tab is not doing anything.

My jQuery:

```
var form = $("#forms");
    form.children("div").steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",

    });
```

The form layout:

```
 <form id="forms" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div>
        <h3>Package Details</h3>
        <section></section>
        <h3>Restaurant</h3>
        <section></section>
        <h3>Address</h3>
        <section></section>
        <h3>Finish</h3>
        <section></section>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: provide jsfiddle if possible

Comment: which is the plugin used

Comment: http://www.jquery-steps.com/

Comment: Please remove div then try

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/4c8pj2u6/

Comment: **[Works fine here too](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/5gsthjga/)**

Comment: Must be another issue else where with my code, some conflict along the line thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#forms").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    autoFocus: true
});
```